# What's the order of loading wordpress elements?

Tags: themes, options

I currently try to make a theme for wordpress and I'm confused about lots of things. I'm not sure what's the order of loading wordpress elements, where some variables are available, where they are saved, etc.

So, about get_option(), in documentation says it's for retriving informations from database, but when you make some fields in theme options and user saves something he entered, that is not stored in database. So this variable is available only during loading wordpress each time?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

WordPress load is complicated process and hard to grasp in full. The very basic overview [would be like this](http://www.rarst.net/images/wordpress_core_load.png).

What you should do for starters - think in specifics. A lot of common tasks (adding scripts, using hooks, etc) are standardized technically or conventionally. So go by task - decide what you want to do and search (and ask if search fails you) what is appropriate way to do it.

PS latter part of your question makes little sense to me, please try to clarify.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer, second part was about get_option(). In wordpress documentation it say "A safe way of getting values for a named option from the options database table", after value is entered here in theme options, it's not saved in database. If I make footer text field, something is saved there, than I can access that field in template files with $array['footer'], but it's NOT saved anywhere in database